# Fetching values as {"property-name": "value"} using pymysql

Tags: python, flask, pymysql

I'm new to Python and I'm building a simple CRUD app using Flask. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
from flask import Flask,request
import pymysql.cursors

connection = pymysql.connect(
host='localhost',
db='mydb',
user='root',
password='password',
cursorclass='pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
)

@app.route('/login',methods=['POST'])
def login():
    cursor = connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute("SELECT id,hash,displayName,attempt,status FROM users WHERE id=%s", (request.form['username']))
    user = cursor.fetchone()
    pprint(user)
```

But this code outputs something like this thing:

```
{u'displayName': 'John Smith',
 u'hash': 'somehash.asdf!@@#$',
 u'id': 'developer',
 u'attempt': 0,
 u'status': 1
}
```

The thing is, I can't seem to get these attributes using the standard `user.hash` syntax. Am I doing something wrong? I need to either:

- convert it to JSON-like structure
- get the properties of `user` when it's presented in this form

Comment: So, you want your output to be JSON?

Comment: @KlausD. I've clarified the question a bit. I'm trying to get the `user`'s property since `user.hash` returns `None` in this case.

Comment: `user["hash"]` to access the hash in the returned `dict`, `json_str = json.dumps(user)` to turn it into a JSON string.

Comment: @zwer That works. Now someone needs to just put it as an answer so I can pick an accepted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a [`pymysql.cursors.DictCursor`](http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) cursor the fetched data is returned as a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), therefore you can use all the common [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) traversal/accessing/modifying methods on it.

This means that you can access your returned *hash* as: `user["hash"]`.

When it comes to JSON, Python comes with a built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module that can readily convert your retrieved `dict` into a JSON string, so in your case, to get a JSON representation of the returned `user` dictionary use:

```
import json

json_string = json.dumps(user)
print(json_string)  # or do whatever you need with it
```